# Vb.Net DataGridView bold font style in only one row

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I need to put only the main topics of the activities in bold (to be highlighted), the DataGridView is automatically filled with a button.

```
Dim Table As New DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Table.Columns.Add("Operation", Type.GetType("System.String"))

    DataGridView1.DataSource = Table


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '----------------ENGINEERING
    Table.Rows.Add("ENGINEERING")
End Sub
```

How can I solve it? Thx!

[Main topics(picture related)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgNIA.jpg)

Comment: You should check DefaultCellStyle property of your row.

Comment: Take a look at the [DataGridView.CellFormatting Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.8). When you get to row you want to be **BOLD** you can set its style properties.

Comment: I need do it in programming language, 'cause it's exclusive for main topics, not overall.

Comment: What determines if the activity is a main topic?

Comment: That it does not have a date.

Comment: Please check the image in my update.

Answer (score 0):

This might help point you in the right direction.  It sets the cell's font to Bold if GetFont is 'True'.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowsAdded
    '--- Make sure we have a row with data in it
    if DataGridView1.rows(e.rowindex) is nothing then exit sub
    if DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "" Then Exit Sub
    '--- Set the font 
    SetFont(DataGridView1.rows(e.rowindex))

End Sub

Private Sub SetFont(pRow as DataGridViewRow)
    Try

           '--- Check if the value is a header
            If pRow.Cells("fecha inicial").Value IsNot Nothing Then
                '--- The value is a header so get the bold font   
                pRow.Cells("opericion").Style.Font = GetFont(True)
            Else
                '--- The value is not a header so get the default font
                pRow.Cells("opericion").Style.Font = GetFont(False)
            End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error ", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub



Private Function GetFont(p As boolean) As Font

    '--- Set the default font
    Dim f As Font = New Font("Verdana", 14)
    If p = True  Then
        '--- Set the font that with the bold 
        f = New Font("Verdana", 14, FontStyle.Bold)
    End If

    Return f


End Function
```

Comment: I try to bold a value assigned to the cell.I can not assign coordinates because the table is generated automatic please check the image in my update.

Comment: You can refer to a cell by using the column name. I used column 0 but you can use row.cell("operacion") or whichever of you cells you want to bold.   When the row is being added decide at that time if it is a header and send your decision into GetFont

Comment: IsAHeader is not defined. :(

Comment: Correct, at the time I didn't know what made a Header so I just tried to give you a hint.  If you want to use that variable then do a Dim IsAHeader as boolean = False, but you will still have to set it to True or False depending on if the row is a header or not.

Comment: I've changed the code a bit and added some comments to help clarify the code.  You'll still have to code the correct check for the date to test if the row is a header.  I just tested that a date is not Nothing.

Comment: Could you send u my project? I have an error, 'cause initially the DataGridView does not show data, all datas are calculated.

Comment: What is ur email? Regards.

Comment: Are you able to edit and put your code into your question?